# 64Bit Version for AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I have to provide a 64 Bit Version of my Android Game which is using AndEngine in Google Play Store. The offical github repo of AndEngine doesn´t provide a 64 bit version of the library. Does anyone have an idea how to convert the library to 64 bit? I tried to add the following:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 x86_64 arm64-v8a
```

line to the "Application.mk" File and ran build.sh. Unfortunately without success.

Did anyone successfully build a 64 Bit Version AndEngine?

Comment: I got it. I will push the updated library to my github account and will add the link here soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the the "build.sh" running and rebuild the native files. I uploaded the updated AndEngine which includes the 64bit native .so files to my github account.

**AndEngine:**

https://github.com/jonnyright/AndEngine

**AndEngine Box2D extension:**

https://github.com/jonnyright/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

Answer (score 3):

Andengine `libandengine.so` file contains just 2 classes `GLES20Fix` and `BufferUtils` , here [they are](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2/jni/src). Here are java classes [GLES20Fix.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/GLES20Fix.java)  and  [BufferUtils.java](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/opengl/util/BufferUtils.java) which call classes from `libandengine.so`. As you can see from java source code and comments C-classes contains workarounds for system bugs [11078](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11078), [16941](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16941), [8931](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8931)  which were in Android 2.2 (froyo), Android 3.0 (honeycomb) and Android 3.2 (honeycomb_mr2).

So, if you don't support android 2.x and 3.x devices you should just delete all `libandengine.so` files from your project. We did so with our project about year ago,  everything works ok.

Comment: Thanks for your for detailed description. My app supports android 4.x above, so this will be a solution. My app uses Box2D extension, so I needed this files so filed for 64 bit too. I got both "build.sh" scripts of andengine and box2d extensions running and have now 64bit .so files for the projects. The app is running with this new generated files.

Comment: Any idea what to do with physcis2d extension project? Should we remove .so files from there as well? Thanks